# watchOS 4: Can you display complications on the photo albums watch face?

Tags: apple-watch, watchos

With watchOS 4, is it possible to display complications on the photo album watch face?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The photo album watch face doesn't seems to exist in watchOS 4 anymore. But the photos watch face do display photos in an photo album. That watch face do supports two complications:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the 'Photos' watch face supports complications including Activity.

It's not possible to display the complication Activity as rings, just as a text.

[image: screen Shot]